# Apps Script - UrlFetchApp.fetch {url, method: "GET"} to a gzip gets failed with code 406

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch

I'm on a multi months quest here. Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm trying to connect via API on App Store Connect using UrlFetchApp.fetch(). After having struggled in the desert to generate the correct JWT for authentification on GAS, I now face harsh reality: the server answer (content-type and content-encoding) is not JSON but GZIP.

Code 406 message:
"Truncated server response: The provided Accept header is not supported for this request. Requested: application/json Allowed: application/a-gzip"

Is there a way to still get access to the file?

Here is the part of the code doing the call only (JWT signature code for authentification is above -> "sJWT")

```
var url = "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports?filter[regionCode]=ZZ&filter[reportDate]=2019-11&filter[reportType]=FINANCIAL&filter[vendorNumber]=xxx"

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { method : "GET", headers : { "Authorization" : "Bearer "+sJWT }});
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw [the official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_finance_reports#response-codes), it is required to use `application/a-gzip` for `Accept` in the request headers.
- And also, in this case, the response returns the content of gzip. So it is required to decompress the content.

When above points are reflected to your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
var url = "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports?filter[regionCode]=ZZ&filter[reportDate]=2019-11&filter[reportType]=FINANCIAL&filter[vendorNumber]=xxx"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + sJWT,
    "Accept": "application/a-gzip"  // Added
  }
});
var res = Utilities.ungzip(response.getBlob());  // Added
```

#### Note:

- Above modified script supposes that the values of your URL and `sJWT` are correct for using the API.

#### References:

- [Download Finance Reports](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_finance_reports#response-codes)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [ungzip(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#ungzipblob)
- [406 Not Acceptable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)

Unfortunately, I cannot test above script. I apologize for this. So if above modified script didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for all those fine details... I enjoyed reading your answer! You were right about using _"Accept": "application/a-gzip"_ in the header, no more code 406. There is nonetheless an error on the decompressing step: _var res = Utilities.ungzip(response.getBlob());_ I've tried to download the file (without decompressing it) using: _DriveApp.createFile(response);_ and I can see that the file doesn't have any extension at the end. Could it be the problem?

Comment: I've also try to download the file via Postman, but this time when I click to "save Response", the file correctly have an extension .txt.gz

Comment: @Dimitri Leroux Thank you for replying. I think that from your replying, it was found that the script works. So no error occurs. I think that the download could be achieved. If you want to use `DriveApp.createFile(response);` for directly saving the response file, please modify to `DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob());`. If you want to give the filename, please use `DriveApp.createFile(response.getBlob().setName("sample.txt.gz"));`.

Comment: @Dimitri Leroux Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the blob content type to "application/x-gzip":

```js
var url = "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports?filter[regionCode]=ZZ&filter[reportDate]=2019-11&filter[reportType]=FINANCIAL&filter[vendorNumber]=xxx"
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + sJWT,
    "Accept": "application/a-gzip"
  }
});
var res = Utilities.ungzip(response.getBlob().setContentType("application/x-gzip"));  // Changed
```