# Using my personal clickup token to make a clickup api call from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, get, urlfetch, clickup-api

```
function getClickupTeam() {
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(clickupUrl + "team", {
    "method": "GET",
    "Authorization": clickupToken,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  })
  Logger.log(response)
  let json = JSON.parse(response);
  Logger.log(json);
}
```

This URLFetchApp call returns {ECODE=OAUTH_017, err=Authorization header required} even though I am including my personal clickup token in the request. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you verify that your token credentials are correct?

Comment: also maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572510/apps-script-urlfetchapp-fetch-url-method-get-to-a-gzip-gets-failed-with?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if I should be including another header labelled token with my personal token or if it should be the value recorded in the "Authorization" field. But it is correct.

Comment: I would try that as it specifies "header" in the error message

Comment: That is not working. I'm not sure the exact syntax that would be required but I can't find anything in the clickup api documentation and a couple of variations all gave the same error code.

Comment: Im still looking but i found this on clickup api documentation: `Authorization Header Required`: The authorization token was missing in the `Authorization` http header. `OAUTH_017`

Comment: what is this for? is it a web-hook or attachment or something else?

Comment: It's for auto-generation and editing of tasks. I have lots of things that have to happen at certain points (checklists added to tasks, members assigned, labels removed) that would use all 10,000 automations given per month very quickly and we can't afford to have that happen.

Comment: one last thing, are you using team id and team url? i notice you add team to the url

Comment: Team is just the highest level object to retrieve from the api. I don't think I need the id if I'm asking the api for the team - https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/clickup20/reference/0/teams/get-teams.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your request is malformed (be sure to check out the reference documentation for the [`UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) method.) The `Authorization` header should be in an explicit `headers` object. Plus, you don't need to set method to `GET` since its the default.

Something else to keep in mind for when you're making `POST` requests - Google Apps Script has this funny quirk where you have to define the `Content-Type` header using the `contentType` property. If you try to set that header in the `headers` object if will just get overridden by the default (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I believe).

So here's how you'd set up your `GET` request:

```js
function getClickupTeam() {
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(clickupUrl + "team", {
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": clickupToken
        }
    }
    
    console.log(response.getContentText());
    let json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    
    console.log(json);
   
);
```

And for `POST` requests with a JSON payload you'd do something like this:

```js
function getClickupTeam() {
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(clickupUrl + "team", {
        "method": "POST",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": clickupToken
        },
        "payload": JSON.stringify({
            "key": "value"
        });
    }
    
    console.log(response.getContentText());
    let json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    
    console.log(json);
   
);
```

Answer (score 1):

While doing some research on the topic through https://clickup.com/api, I stumbled across some code. There are a couple of different ones for different things, I'd recommend the first, JavaScript (as that's whats closest to what your currently doing). In a comment you said it was for editing tasks so that's what this code is aimed for.

javascript

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('PUT', 'https://api.clickup.com/api/v1/task/{task_id}');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '"access_token"');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

var body = {
  'name': 'New Task Name',
  'content': 'New Task Content',
  'assignees': {
    'add': [
      1
    ],
    'rem': [
      2
    ]
  },
  'status': 'Closed',
  'priority': 3,
  'due_date': '1508369194377'
};

request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

curl

```
curl --include \
     --request PUT \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "Authorization: "access_token"" \
     --data-binary "{
    \"name\": \"New Task Name\",
    \"content\": \"New Task Content\",
    \"assignees\": {
        \"add\" : [
            1
        ],
        \"rem\" : [
            2
        ]
    },
    \"status\": \"Closed\",
    \"priority\": 3,
    \"due_date\": \"1508369194377\"
}" \
'https://api.clickup.com/api/v1/task/{task_id}'
```

node.js

```js
var request = require('request');

request({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://api.clickup.com/api/v1/task/{task_id}',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': '\'access_token\''
  },
  body: "{  \"name\": \"New Task Name\",  \"content\": \"New Task Content\",  \"assignees\": {    \"add\": [      1    ],    \"rem\": [      2    ]  },  \"status\": \"Closed\",  \"priority\": 3,  \"due_date\": \"1508369194377\"}"
}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('Status:', response.statusCode);
  console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  console.log('Response:', body);
});
```

This is aimed for production let me know if you need `mock server` or `debugging proxy`

Comment: I found this online too and it did not help me as XMLHttpRequest is not available on GAS. This is also for their v1 api which is deprecated.

Comment: i must say I don't Know what else to try are you sure the method is get not post?

Comment: did you try with Curl?

Comment: Google apps script doesn't support curl unfortunately. I may end up just writing it in a node.js app and hosting it somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I plus one'd your answer. I'm currently working with clickup's support team. I'll answer my own question if they're able to help me.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, and good luck. Sorry I couldn't help!